# FullCalendar events table connot have foreign key?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar jQuery plugin in which users can add events to a database table..

This is my events table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events]
(
    [EventID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [Start] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndT] [datetime] NULL,
    [ThemeColor] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [IsFullDay] [bit] NULL,
    [userID] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY [EventID]
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Events]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Events_Users] 
        FOREIGN KEY([userID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([userID])
```

It works well and the getEvents function successes .. But, When I tried to associate the events table with another table in the database (add a foreign key that reference another table like the users table)

```
[userID] [int] NOT NULL,
```

the fullCalendar fails to load .. I can not even see the calendar on the page

If I remove the relationship it works..

How can I make it work without removing the relationship as I need to know the events belongs to which user..??

Thanks

I'm using SQL Server ..

Comment: Your table script isn't complete - *what* column(s) is the primary key made up of?? Also, please show how the `Events` table is associated with the `Users` table (what SQL did you use to establish that association?)

Comment: I have update it